# sobolev spaces integral estimation

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

if I have a sequence $f_k\in W_{1,p}(\Omega)$ which converge weakly to some function $ f $

and I know that $\nabla f_k-\nabla f\to 0$ in $L_{p}^{loc}(\Omega)$

I try to estimate the integral $\int_{\tilde{\Omega}} |\nabla f_k|^p-|\nabla f|^p$

$\tilde{\Omega}\subset \Omega$ (actually I try to prove it is 0 if $dist(\tilde{\Omega},\partial \Omega)>0 $

is there any suggestion for how to do this?

Comment: Since the restriction of gradient to $\widetilde {\Omega}$ converges in $L^p$, the $L^p$ norms converge.

Comment: this is what I wanted to prove, what theorem you rely on?

Comment: Triangle inequality for the norm.

Comment: the convergence is weak

Comment: But you have the strong convergence of the gradient on $\tilde\Omega$.

Comment: By $\tilde \Omega\subset\Omega$, do you mean $\tilde \Omega$ is compacted supported in $\Omega$? If yes, then the result is try.